# how to convert list to dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this:

```
l = ["a" ,"b" ,"c" ,"d" ,"e" ,"i" ,"i" ,"e"]
```

and I want it like that and with quantity of every key:

```
 l =  {"a":"1", "b":"1", "c":"1", "d":"1", "e":"2" ,"i":"2"}
```

Comment: Do you want to count elements in the list?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "i", "i", "e"]
>>> Counter(l)
Counter({'e': 2, 'i': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Comment: Holy Moly that was fast.

Answer (score 0):

the .get() method can be used to tally https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm

the line below creates two variables, your list and an empty dictionary:

```
l, dct = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ,"i" , "i", "e"], {}
```

then loop through each element in your list and use .get() which checks if a dictionary "key" exists, if it doesn't it will create it and also if it doesn't already exist sets a default "value":

```
for element in l: dct [element] = dct.get(element, 0)+1
```

in the above case the default value is 0 if the key does not already exist, if it does exist it will +1 to the existing value for dictionary key [element]

then print the dictionary

```
print (dct)
```

prints:

```
{'i': 2, 'd': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'a': 1, 'e': 2}
```